# Welcher Kasus in »überlässt das Töten wen/wem anderen«?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, pronoun

Ist hier Dativ oder Akkusativ richtig?

> Somit sucht sich der Jäger im Wald sein Essen und geht nicht einfach in den Supermarkt und überlässt das Töten **wen/wem** anderen.

Comment: MAnuel, welcome to the site! You might want to edit your post to clarify: *What exactly is your question*? And before you do so, I suggest taking the [tour] and visiting our [help]. [Here](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will find more on "asking good questions". And finally a personal hint: The more effort you put into your question, the more effort others are likely to put into their answers - this is not a paid service but a bunch of volunteers willing to help others.

Comment: I hope I did understand the question correctly. Feel free to update the question anyway. Once your question states properly what the issue is, vote for reopen.

Comment: 1. Ich sehe keinen Grund die Frage zu schließen. Auch vor Em1's Überarbeitung war klar, was der OP wissen wollte. Hier werden generell viel zu viele Fragen geschlossen (und immer von denselben Leuten!) 2. Ich würde zur Frage gerne eine Antwort schreiben. Warum geht das nicht?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Es ist *nicht* klar, was der OP wissen wollte. Hat er ein Problem mit der Formenbildung von _wer_? Mit den Kasus, die _überlassen_ regiert? Mit etwas völlig anderem? Solange du das nicht weißt, kannst du auch nicht sinnvoll antworten. (Durch die Bearbeitung ist die Frage lesbarer geworden, aber auch der Warum-Teil einfach verschwunden; der Rest ist leicht zu beantworten, hilft aber niemandem weiter.) Ansonsten wäre das Gegenstand für eine Diskussion auf Meta.

Comment: Dativ ist hier übrigens richtig. Die generelle Grammatik des Satzes ist jedoch haarsträubend. Es müsste heißen *... überlässt das Töten jemand anderem*.

Comment: Ich weiß, dass das nach Meta gehört, aber ich finde, dass hingerotzte Fragen geschlossen werden sollten, bis der Fragesteller selber zeigt, dass er gewillt ist, zwei Minuten zu investieren.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Und im Zweifelsfall ist *ganz weglassen* auch eine Option... ^_^

Comment: So weit ich es verstehen kann, dann will der Fragesteller wissen, welchen Kasus im Satz benutzt werden sollte - und warum. Auch wenn ich die Überschrift, die Frage und den Satz etwas merkwürdig formuliert finde.

Comment: @stephie Jo. Ich lasse mal meinen "Antwortkommentar" drin.

Answer (score 5):

Der Dativ ist hier der richtige Fall, denn es heißt

> jemandem (Dat.) etwas überlassen

"Richtig" ist also

> ... und überlässt das Töten wem anderen.

Der Satz ist in dieser Form allerdings aus meiner Sicht vom Ausdruck her eine Katastrophe. Wäre ich Lehrer würde ich's anstreichen.

Aus meiner Sicht müsste es heißen

> ... und überlässt das Töten jemand anderem.

oder

> ... und überlässt das Töten anderen (Plural!)